# Theorem $2$ (Variational principle for the principal eigenvalue)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, elliptic-operators

I'm trying understand the Theorem $2$ (Variational principle for the principal eigenvalue) in the section of the eigenvalues of the elliptic symmetric operator on  chapter $6$ of the Evans' book and I'm stuck in steps $5$, $6$, $7$ and $8$ of the proof. I will put the whole proof and the motivation of the weak solution below.

My doubts are

$1.$ Why $\lambda_1$ has finite multiplicity imply that $u = \sum_\limits{k=1}^m (u,w_k) w_k$ in the step $5$?

$2.$ Why $B[u^+,u^+] = \lambda_1 ||u^+||^2_{L^2(U)}$ and $B[u^-,u^-] = \lambda_1 ||u^-||^2_{L^2(U)}$? I can't see why the previous equality ensures this.

$3.$ Why $(19)$ and $(20)$ holds by the step $5$? This step ensures the result follows for normalized functions with respect to the norm of $L^2(U)$ and we assume $||u||_{L^2(U)}^2 = 1$, but not assume this for $u^+$ and $u^-$.

$4.$ Why exist $\chi \in \mathbb{R}$ with the property mentioned in the step $8$? I would understand if the $u$ and $\tilde{u}$ would be constants, but they are functions. How to ensure the existence of this constant in this case?

Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Equation $(8)$ states that $$ u = \sum_{k=1}^\infty d_kw_k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (u,w_k) w_k. $$ The line before says that $d_k = 0$ if $\lambda_k>\lambda_1$, which means that the only terms that preserves in the infinite sum are the terms $d_kw_k$ with $w_k$ the eigenfunctions corresponding to $\lambda_1$. Since $\lambda_1$ has multiplicity, say $m$, it follows that there are $m$ eigenfunctions corresponding to $\lambda_1$ and so 
   $$ u = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (u,w_k)w_k = \sum_{k=1}^m (u,w_k)w_k. $$
2. On the equality just before the claim, note that we use the \emph{Rayleigh formula} (See the equivalent statement of this in the Remarks), which asserts that $$ \lambda_1\le \frac{B[v,v]}{\|v\|_{L^2(U)}^2} \ \ \textrm{ for any $v\in H_0^1(U), v\neq 0$}. $$ In particular, 
   \begin{align*}
   \lambda_1 = B[u,u] & = \color{red}{B[u^+,u^+]} + B[u^-,u^-] \\
   & \ge \color{red}{\lambda_1\|u^+\|_{L^2(U)}^2} + \color{blue}{B[u^-,u^-]} \\
   & \ge \lambda_1\|u^+\|_{L^2(U)}^2 + \color{blue}{\lambda_1\|u^-\|_{L^2(U)}^2} \\
   & = (\alpha + \beta)\lambda_1 = \lambda_1. 
   \end{align*}
   Since we start with $\lambda_1$ and end up with $\lambda_1$, this means that every inequality that we used must in fact be an equality, i.e. the blue expressions must equal to each other and similarly for red.
3. You are correct that $u^+$ and $u^-$ are not normalised so you can't really invoke the claim in Step $5$ (called this Claim $1$). But one can actually prove the following similar claim by adapting the proof of Claim $1$: If $u\in H_0^1(U)\setminus 0$, then $u$ is a weak solution of 
   \begin{alignat*}{2}
   Lu & = \lambda_1u && \ \ \textrm{ in $U$} \\
   u & = 0 && \ \ \textrm{ on $\partial U$}, 
   \end{alignat*}
   if and only if $\lambda_1\|u\|_{L^2(U)}^2 = B[u,u]$.
4. In Step $8$, since we assume that $u$ and $\tilde u$ are two nontrivial (i.e. $u, \tilde u\neq 0$) weak solutions of $(10)$, it follows from $(16)$ and $(17)$ that either $u>0$ in $U$ or $u<0$ in $U$, and similarly for $\tilde u$. In particular, this means that 
   $$ A\colon = \int_U u\, dx \neq 0 \ \ \textrm{ and } \ \ B\colon = \int_U \tilde u\, dx \neq 0. $$
   But these integrals $A$ and $B$ are just real numbers (well, convince yourself that these integrals are finite number). The existence of $\chi$ is clear here, since one is really asking: can I find $\chi$ such that $A-\chi B = 0$? Yes, pick $\chi = A/B$ (which is well-defined since $B\neq 0$).

Comment: I understood the items $2$ and $4$, thanks, but I'm not sure if I understood the items $1$ and $3$. Item $1$ you state that the multiplicity $m$ of $\lambda_1$ implies that there are $m$ eigenfunctions because the operator $L$ is diagonalizable, i.e., admits an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors by the item $(iii)$ of the [previous theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901202/eigenvalues-of-symmetric-elliptic-operators) of this section, then the algebraic multiplicity and geometric multiplicity of $\lambda_1$ coincides, right?

Comment: On the item $3$, I agree with you, but this holds for $u$. Even if I applied this argument  which you mention for $u^+$, I think I would have that the $L\frac{u^+}{||u^+||_{L^2(U)}} = \lambda_1 \frac{u^+}{||u^+||_{L^2(U)}}$ in $U$ and $\frac{u^+}{||u^+||_{L^2(U)}} = 0$ in $\partial U$.

Comment: Correct for your first comment. For item 3, I just simply decided not to normalise $u^+$ like you did; what you have is absolutely correct if you decide to apply the claim in step 5 with $v = u^+/\|u^+\|_{L^2(U)}$. Nonetheless, you should see that this doesn't affect the argument in Step 7!

Comment: I think I understood why $(19)$ and $(20)$ holds by your answer of my question $3$, it's because it was proved that $B[u^+,u^+] = \lambda_1 ||u^+||^2_{L^2(U)}$ and $B[u^-,u^-] = \lambda_1 ||u^-||^2_{L^2(U)}$, right?

Comment: Yep! The claim that Evan had in Step $5$ and the claim that I wrote in my answer are similar in nature, in the sense that Evans had $u$ normalised and I didn't.

Comment: @CheeHan Hello! There is something I don't understand in Step 7. 1. The strong maximum principle implies either $u^+>0$ or $u^+ \equiv 0$ in $U$, and $u^->0$ or $u^- \equiv 0$ in $U$, but I can't see why this ensures $u$ (which equals $u^+-u^-$) is either positive or negative in $U$, could you please explain it for me? 2. Is it true that either $u^+>0$ or $u^+ \equiv 0$ a.e. in $U$ when $a^{ij}$ are merely $L^\infty$? It seems that we need some kind of strong maximum principle for weak solutions, does there exist such kind of strong maximum principle? Thank you very much!

Comment: The second question is elucidated in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4128232/709713

Comment: @WentaoHu if $u^+=0$, then $u=-u^- < 0$ in $U$. If instead $u^+ = \max(u,0) > 0$ in $U$, then  $u>0$ everywhere in $U$ follows because $\max(a,b)>b$ iff $a>b$.